# Why dojo EnhancedGrid doesn't automatically save to store with row structure as alwaysEditing to true?

Tags: javascript, dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid

I am having an issue in using `dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid` with structure of row as `{ "editable: true, alwaysEditing: true" }`. The `dojox.grid.cells.textbox` and `dojox.grid.cells.selectbox` don't automatically save to store after we change it in input values. Most of times the `onStartEdit`, `onApplyCellEdit` functions are also not triggered here. 
What is the problem here?

**Javascript**

```
var grid = new dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid({
    store: store,
    autoWidth: true,
    onApplyCellEdit: function() { alert('saved editing'); },
    structure: [
        { name: "Item Number", field: "col1", width: "84px", editable: true, alwaysEditing: true  },
        { name: "Item Description", field: "col2", width: "84px" },
        { name: "Stock/Non Stock", field: "col3", width: "84px" }
    ]
}, "grid");
```

If we remove `"alwaysEditing: true"` from structure, every thing will work correct. The store will be automatically saved and `onStartEdit`, `onApplyCellEdit` functions will be triggered.

If we use normal datagrid(`dojox.grid.DataGrid`) instead of `dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid`. with structure `{ "editable: true, alwaysEditing: true" }` of row everything will works fine.

Please give me solution to get the `alwaysEditing: true`  to get store be updated and with triggering of these following function `onStartEdit`, `onApplyCellEdit` too using with dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid.

Please find [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/twRkv/2/) where EnhancedGrid doesn't trigger `onApplyCellEdit` function and automatically save store with row structure as `alwaysEditing` to `true`. The demo sometimes trigger `onApplyCellEdit`, but most of times it doesn't.

Please find [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/twRkv/3/) where EnhancedGrid trigger `onApplyCellEdit` function and save store on removing `alwaysEditing` from row structure. Please double click on first column to get field in editable mode.

Please give me a solution where EnhancedGrid supports `alwaysEditing` with save store and trigger `onApplyCellEdit` function.

May I know is this a bug with dojo EnhancedGrid?

Comment: Is there a particular browser where this doesn't work? Both fiddles seem to trigger `onApplyCellEdit` for me.

Comment: @Frode The `onApplyCellEdit` function doesn't trigger all on change in Firefox 26.0. Sometimes it is working, some cases it is not working...  Try with editing different first column.